# Moq'ing an interface

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, moq

While I'm googling/reading for this answer I thought I would also ask here.

I have a class that is a wrapper for a SDK.  The class accepts an ILoader object and uses the ILoader object to create an ISBAObject which is cast into an ISmallBusinessInstance object. I am simply trying to mock this behavior using Moq.

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Customer_GetByID()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ILoader>();

        var sbainst = new Mock<ISbaObjects>();

        mock.Expect(x => x.GetSbaObjects("")).Returns(sbainst);


    }
```

The compiler error reads: Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'Moq.Language.IReturns.Returns(Microsoft.BusinessSolutions.SmallBusinessAccounting.Loader.ISbaObjects)' has some invalid arguments

What is going on here?  I expected the Mock of ISbaObjects to be able to be returned without a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use sbainst.Object, as sbinst isn't an instance of ISbaObjects - it's just the mock part.

Answer (score 2):

Updated, correct code

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Customer_GetByID()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILoader>();

    var sbainst = new Mock<ISbaObjects>();

    mock.Expect(x => x.GetSbaObjects("")).Returns(sbainst.Object);


}
```